# How to use AND & OR in powerquery Fromulas?

Tags: powerquery

I want to use Power Query `Text.Contains` function to check if the text contains one of my specified values. 
Example:

```
If Text.Contains([#"My Columns"], ("a" OR "b" OR "c")) Then "Found" Else "Not Found"
```

I've already tested syntax like:

```
Text.Contains([#"My Columns"], {"a","b","c"})

Text.Contains([#"My Columns"], ("a"||"b"||"c"))
```

But I got error message, does anybody know how can I use AND & OR in Power Query's Formulas?

Comment: Would you like to share the error message so that people better know what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use Text.PositionOfAny, something like:

`if Text.PositionOfAny( [My Columns] , { "a", "b" , "c" } )  = -1 then "Not Found" else "Found"`

Note PQ formulas are (irritatingly) case sensitive so "if" "then" and "else" must be lower case, and the function name must be mixed case exactly as above.

The above code assumes you have a single column named "My Columns".  If you actually want to search across multiple columns, then just add a "Merge Columns" step upstream (from the Add Column ribbon).

Comment: Thanks Mike :), yeah used this